# Login into website

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to login into a website with "requests" but when I print the reponse I obtain the login webpage instead of the next step:

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://loginwebpage.cgi'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'pass'
    rget = c.get(url,verify=False)
    login_data = {'username':username, 'password':password}
    request = c.post(url, data=login_data)
    print request.text
```

Does anyone know why I can't login?

I expected to see the source code of the index page in the reponse but what I obtain is the code of the login page (that means that I have not login).

E.g. :

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'loginwebsite.cgi'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'pass'
    login_data = {'username':username, 'password':password}
    LoginRequest = c.post(url, data=login_data,verify=False)

    AuthRequest=c.get('IndexWebpage.html')

    if LoginRequest.text==AuthRequest.text: 
        print "The source code is the same !"
```

And this is the output :

> The source code is the same !

Comment: what is next step?

Comment: The index webpage (the webpage after the login form)

Comment: nobody knows? I always obtain the same url